# Find a polynomial with integral coefficients whose zeros include $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Find a polynomial with integral coefficients whose zeros include $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$.

I think I can use $-3= (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5})(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5})$ and a certain telescopic factorisation. The problem is that I don't know how to continue this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Comment: Hint:  if $\alpha$ is your number then $\alpha^2-7=2\sqrt {10}$

Comment: It's true that if a polynomial with integral coefficients has $a+\sqrt b$ as a root ($a,b$ integers, $b$ not a square), then it must also have $a-\sqrt b$ as a root. (You've probably noticed this for quadratic polynomials.) So for the given problem, you could take a leap of faith and write down the polynomial whose four roots are $\pm\sqrt2\pm\sqrt5$ and see what happens...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may observe that
$$
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5})^2=7+2\sqrt{10}
$$ giving
$$\left((\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5})^2-7\right)^2= (2\sqrt{10})^2=40.$$ Thus $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$ is a root of
$$P(X)= (X^2-7)^2-40=X^4-14X^2+9.$$

Comment: Nice solution.  What prompted you to square it, move the integer, and then square it again? Was it an attempt to remove radicals?

Comment: @SRobertJames Thank you, yes it was :)